# For a Russian visa, do I need to disclose a driving offence?

Tags: visas, driving, applications, russia, criminal-records

My partner pleaded guilty to dangerous driving in 2017 and he received a ban.

Does it need to be disclosed on the Russian Visa application?

Comment: It's unclear if you're asking a) if the Russian visa application contains a question or questions about bans or driving offenses, or b) if your partner must answer truthfully. I don't know the answer to the first; the answer to the second is "yes."

Comment: What country was the driving offence in?

Comment: I just need to know if it goes on the application form as it is a driving offence

Comment: @user104330 Is there a specific question relevant to it on the application form? Eg a question(s) asking about fines, cautions, criminal convictions? Dangerous driving is likely to fall within the latter category.

Comment: "Does it need to be disclosed" The question would be more clear if asked in the active voice. As it is, it leaves the impression that you might be asking whether *you* need to disclose it on *your* application, especially since the question tile specifically says "do i need to". Also, it's not clear what "ban" means here.

Comment: @Acccumulation It’s a logical assumption that ‘ban’ refers to a driving ban - usually automatic for serious driving offences.

Answer (score 2):

In Russia's legal system, there is a distinct difference between **criminal offence** (уголовное преступление) and anything else: "administrative", i.e. civil, offence or fines imposed by road police.

If your driving offence can be considered criminal, then yes, you should. If it can't, then better skip it. What kind of court settled your case? Did you get any penalty other than getting driving ban? That's the questions your partner needs to answer.

Answer (score 1):

On an [archived version of the application form](http://www.rusembassy.ca/sites/default/files/AppFormVisa_USA.pdf), it asks:

> Have you ever been arrested or convicted for any offence?

You said your partner was convicted for a driving offence, therefore the answer is yes. He shouldn’t get a refusal simply on the basis of that, there are other factors to consider as well.

Comment: Immigrations systems of less democratic countries aren’t entirely transparent.